# React Native: Network request failed for HTTPS in device

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I am using https connection for REST API, While hitting POST request through iPhone device am getting Network Request Failed error but in the simulator, it's working without any issue.

Note: If I generate IPA in release mode, For some time it getting work, after that again facing the same Network Request Failed Error.

I have changed my info.plist to like below

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>localhost</key>
    <dict>           
      <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

But still, am facing this issue only in iPhone device.

Comment: When running your app on the phone, `localhost` will be the phone itself.  This probably isn't what you want - You need the IP address of your server (PC)

Comment: @Paulw11 I have changed that "localhost" to my IP and tried, Still faced the same issue

Comment: What is the error code?  Any other detail from the message?